# Angular doesn't send file to API even though formData.has('file') gives "true". The Laravel API receives a file from Postman

Tags: angular, file-upload, laravel-api

On Angular frontend, for Upload File function, I can't send a file to Laravel 9 API. With Postman, everything goes well, the array is not empty, but from Angular - the array is comes empty.

I checked my Angular, FormData.has(file) gives "true" in console.log(). When I test with Postman, everything goes well, the array is not empty. And from Angular - the array is comes empty.
To avoid an error with CORS by using proxy in my Angular. All other POST requests except Upload File in Angular work well.

Response (Angular - Laravel):

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag)#48 (1) {
["parameters":protected]=>
  array(0) {}
}
```

Response (Postman - Laravel):

```
object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\FileBag)#48 (1) {
  ["parameters":protected]=>
  array(1) {
    ["file"]=>
    object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile)#33 (6) {
      ["test":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
      bool(false)
      ["originalName":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
      string(20) "contactsImporter.xls"
      ["mimeType":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
      string(24) "application/vnd.ms-excel"
      ["error":"Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile":private]=>
      int(0)
      ["pathName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
      string(45) "C:\Users\dmitr\AppData\Local\Temp\phpF12E.tmp"
      ["fileName":"SplFileInfo":private]=>
      string(11) "phpF12E.tmp"
    }
  }
}
```

```
/Laravel/

public function importContact(Request $request){
    var_dump($request->files);exit;

    if (!$request->hasFile('file') && !$request->file('file')->isValid()) {
        return response()->json('{"error": "please provide a file"}');

    } 

    //...
}
```

```
/Angular/

<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="submitForm()">
    <input enctype="multipart/form-data" type="file" (change)="uploadFile($event)">
    <button>Upload</button>
</form>
```

```
uploadFile(event: Event) {    
    const fileContacts = (event.target as HTMLInputElement)?.files?.[0]; 
    console.log(fileContacts); 
    this.form.patchValue({
          file: fileContacts
    });
}

submitForm() {
    const formData: any = new FormData();
    formData.append('file', this.form.controls['file'].value);
    console.log(formData.has('file'));

    const httpOptions = {
          headers: new HttpHeaders({
                'Content-type': 'multipart/form-data',
                'Accept': 'application/json' 
          })
    };

    return this.http.post(this.url+'contacts/importContact', formData, httpOptions)
    .subscribe({
          next: (v) => console.log('success: ', v),
          error: (e) => console.error('error while uploading file', e),
          complete: () => console.info('complete')      
    })
}
```

Comment: it looks like your code is working, check this: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-eq8ajy

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately gives an error Http failure response for http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/contacts/importContact: 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: error 500 means your server can't handle the request

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yes, the code is working. I tested in another Angular application. Everything is working. Thank you!